# Black screen with static cursor on Kali Linux 2018.3 on VirtualBox

Tags: virtualbox, kali-linux

After importing the `.ova` file of the latest Linux Kali release ([found here](https://www.offensive-security.com/kali-linux-vm-vmware-virtualbox-hyperv-image-download/)) into VirtualBox, and successfully booting into the OS from GRUB, I'm greeted with a black screen and a static (non-blinking) cursor:

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kpYlO.png)

The VirtualBox will not respond to any input what-so-ever, neither keyboard strokes nor mouse clicks.

Several people have had this problem over the years, but none of the suggested solutions have worked for me. These solutions include:

- Setting the VirtualBox view to Auto-scale,
- Disabling 3D-acceleration (this was disabled by default), and
- Adding `nomodeset` to the Grub command line (as suggested [here](https://community.linuxmint.com/tutorial/view/842)).

How do I solve this?

Comment: I just saw that my source for the .ova is not an official Kali linux release, but a VirtualBox image from some site called 'offensive security'. I'll try to download the .iso from official sources.

Comment: I have the black screen problem with the latest Kali VirtualBox Image 2019.2 with Virtualbox 5. I updated to Virtualbox 6, and the problem is solved. Kali VirtualBox Image is usually made for the latest virtualbox, so it's a good idea to keep your Virtualbox up to date, if you encounter any problems.

Comment: Adding nomodeset to the Grub command line is the only solution that worked for me. I'm using Virtualbox 5, so I cannot confirm if version 6 still has this issue

Answer (score 0):

Most likely you've downloaded the VMWare image. There is a tab on the download page that has the Virtual Box downloads. You can use the SHA256 checksum listed on the page to verify which version you've downloaded.